# How to fix "Could not find or load main class" in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, terminal

Whenever I run any java file in vscode it gives me the same error in the below.

I can still run java files regularly in my terminal with javac and java, but it won't let me do it whenever I try to do it with vscode. How can I fix this?

Here is the error it gives:

cd /Users/pc/Documents/1501 ; /usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/idk-20.idk/Contents/Home/bin/ia va -XX: +ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp /Users/pc/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/c159494a564a4bbb939d3417£409392/ redhat.java/idt ws/1501 46c8f262/bin test
Error: Could not find or load main class test
Caused by: java. lang. ClassNotFoundException: test

whenever I ls into "/Users/pc/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/c159494a564a4bbb939d3417£409392/ redhat.java/idt ws/1501 46c8f262/bin test" there are 3 text files but no .class files. Could this be the problem or how do I fix it?

Here is a list of thinks I tried:

- Reinstalling vscode and all java extensions
- Clean the java language server workspace

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Make sure your filename is the same as the main class name and then execute the code using `Run Java` or the `Run` button at the top of the code.